# How to extract Z data from a shapefile from points on another separate layer QGIS

Tags: qgis, layers, elevation, spatial-query

I have two layers; one with elevation data (m), and the other with roads (derived from points via points to polyines). I want to run a spatial query that basically extracts the elevation data from the start and end nodes of each link. The core function sounds like a common scenario many users may face. Is there a way of doing this?

I have provided an image to help. The blue lines are roads, and the red lines is the elevation data.

[image]

Comment: You will likely have better luck using a raster data type, such as a DEM, as a source of your elevation data. Elevation contours represent the elevation only along the contour lines.

Comment: Using GRASS GIS in QGIS' Processing you can upload raster values at positions of vector points to the attribute table, see https://grass.osgeo.org/grass74/manuals/v.what.rast.html (this requires a DEM derived from the contour lines).

Comment: Since qgis 3.4 there's a built in tool for "draping" vectors over a raster, setting the z value for coordinates to values sampled from the raster. If you converted your source vector to raster via interpolation you could the run this tool to update the z values of the destination layer.

Answer (score 1):

**With the data you have, you can *estimate* elevation at the end of each road as follows:**

1. Select the start and end points in your point layer, and (optionally) save them as a separate layer.
2. Install the refFunctions plugin.
3. Add the elevation of the nearest contour line to the point layer's attribute table, by using this expression `geomnearest('contourLayer','elevationField')` in the Field Calculator.

   - substitute the name of your contour layer where the expression says 'contourLayer'
   - if the elevation is stored as an attribute table field, substitute the name of that attribute where the expression says 'elevationField'
   - if the elevation is stored as a Z value rather than as an attribute, use the expression `$z`

---

As reevesii suggested, you will have better accuracy using elevation in raster format. Contour lines only represent the elevation along the line, so if your roads don't end exactly on a contour line the elevation of the nearest contour line won't be accurate for that point.

**To calculate more accurate elevation for the end of each road:**

1. [Acquire a DEM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_elevation_model#Sources) (digital elevation model) raster for your area of interest. DEMs are available for free from many sources, such as [Natural Earth](https://www.naturalearthdata.com/) and the [United States Geological Survey](https://www.usgs.gov/faqs/where-can-i-get-elevation-data).
2. Select the road start and end points in your point layer.
3. Use the `Sample raster values` tool to add elevation values from the DEM to the selected points.

Comment: Hi, thanks for everyone's input. The elevation data is a shapefile - which already has the elevation (m). The shapefile is 10m intervals - as we require a higher resolution in comparison to other free layers.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute the [Feature Vertices to Points](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/feature-vertices-to-points.htm) tool (requires Advanced license) and choose the option END for the Point Type parameter.  This will give you a point feature class of the start/end point.  Next, execute the [Extract Values to Points](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/extract-values-to-points.htm) tool (requires Spatial Analyst extension) to extract the elevation from the raster dataset.

Comment: This answer is for ArcGIS; the question is about QGIS.